# how to create a window that changes text with input GTK

Tags: c, gtk

Hi guys I'm using GTK to create a GUI for my program (written in c), but have no idea how to display a text on a window that changes with the change of the input. Any help please?

e.g. (input is "A")

window will display A

input changes to B

window will display B

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is an entry, add a label to the window B and connect the entry's `changed` signal to a callback that updates the label the new text.